# SSH Tunneling and Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, ssh

I am working on a project for an app that allows Android to remotely connect to an MySQL Database using a PHP API.

Users have requested that the app should support SSH Tunneling which I have been looking into but I have a few concerns regarding this.

How the app works is the API runs on my web server (the user has the option to install on there own servers but most don't) so Android sends a post to the PHP API, and then PHP directly connect to a MySQL Host that was sent in the post message from android, this is all working fine.

However, if I want to support SSH tunneling, my understanding is that my Android app would still post to my PHP API, but instruct to open an SSH tunnel, for example forwarding local port 3307 to remote host example.com on port 3306. Then PHP would connect to MySQL via 127.0.0.1 on port 3307.

This is fine, except if another user then decides to use port 3307 at the same time another user is doing a tunnel the second user would clash as the first user already has 3307 open so they would need to pick a new port.

I thought that then the best work around for this would be the API has a pool of sockets that it can use and picks one that is free and connects via that local port via the specified remote port that android sent. E.g. the API will for example pick local port 5000 and forward to 3306.

My worry here is that although this would work, there is a potential risk that two users could make a request at the same time, and the API picks the same port number to use as a local port, e.g. 5000, as this port is technically free but then one user would successfully connect, and the second user would end up connecting to the first users servers, and hopefully fail to authenticate but still, potential risk here.

Am I thinking of this the correct way, or is there a better way, or should I only support the SSH tunneling option if the user is running the API from there own web server instead of mine so there would be no risk of clashing with another unrelated user.

Comment: If they are sophisticated enough to use SSH tunnelling as a user, they should be sophisticated enough to manually configure a port in a settings screen, when they provide the username, password, etc. for configuring the tunnel itself. "should I only support the SSH tunneling option if the user is running the API from there own web server instead of mine" -- um, that's the only option. Baking SSH user credentials in your app is a **much** bigger problem than socket collisions, IMHO.

Comment: One question: _why_ using a tunnel _and_ http/php? So _two_ transport layers? If just for encryption, then simply use https to access the API, no need for a tunnel. If no http based transport should be used (whyever), but the database should be used directly through the tunnel, then you have no API in between, but the apps act as sql clients. Again: _why_?

Comment: A tunnel has been requested by several users of the app (the app is already released), the database can't be accessed directly, even via a tunnel as Android doesn't support it, so android has to post to a PHP API in order to do the MySQL stuff

Comment: could you explain better these two statements. (1) `However, if I want to support SSH tunneling, my understanding is that Android would still post via PHP, but instruct to open an SSH tunnel,...` and (2) `even via a tunnel as Android doesn't support it`

Comment: I've reworded statement 1, hopefully makes more sense, as for statement 2, I mean I can't connect to the database directly, either with or without a tunnel as Android doesn't have a MySQL library so has to reply on posting to a PHP API.

Comment: So now the phrase *Users have requested that the app should support SSH Tunneling* is a reference to non-Android users then ? Clearly the answer should be that you are not referring to Android users.

Comment: Not sure what you mean there, they're android users as they're using my android app, from some more research it doesn't look like what I want do is possible.

Comment: That is why I am confused why you went into talking about PHP making tunnel requests, as if somehow your users were interfacing through their own PHP servers or something ! As if, "hey, we now have SSH tunnels" ... but not for them though :P

Comment: By default the app will use my web server, but the user of the app does have the option to install the API on there web servers so there web server would be creating the tunnel instead of my server

Comment: So maybe ponder it all and see if you could determine what is possible, and tweak the question. Narrow it. Rein it in. Make it one third the word count

Comment: If you want to mull it over, I am over in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/random-musings-drew